# SQL query - Insert list of ids if not exists in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with `EmpId` and `CategroyId`.

During insert, there can be duplicates, where the same `EmpId` and `CategoryId` are already in the table. I want to exclude the already existing mapped values of `EmpId` -a `CategoryId` and insert rest of the mapping.

I know we can try with not exists but is there any other way to achieve this? using joins?

Consider the below table as the existing values:

```
EmpID  CategoryId
------------------
  1       11
  1       12
  2       13
```

This is the array I'm trying to insert

```
EmpID  CategoryId
-------------------
  1       11
  1       12
  1       13 
  1       14
```

So I want only the below values to be inserted, excluding the already existing ones.

```
EmpID  CategoryId
------------------
1       13 
1       14
```

Comment: Why would you prefer a join over `not exists`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwjANcqrvX4eTJmQus7mSp/0).

```
insert into table1(EmpiId, CategoryId)
select
    EmpiID,
    CategoryId
from table2 t2
where not exists (
  select
    EmpiID
  from table1 t1
  where t2.EmpiID = t1.EmpiID
  and t2.CategoryId = t1.CategoryId
 )
```

output of select statement:

```
| EmpiID | CategoryId |
| ------ | ---------- |
| 1      | 13         |
| 1      | 14         |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one - using `left join`

```
inset into existing_table(empid, categoryid)
  select a.empid, a.category from new_table a
     left join existing_table b on a.empid=b.empid and a.CategoryId=b.CategoryId
  where b.empid is null and b.CategoryId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using LEFT JOIN with condition EmpId IS NULL.
Tell me if you an example